# How to call anonymous functions from HTML components' events using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button. I registered a function to treat the *click* event. However, I want to call it if another event happens. How do I call it from another asynchronous (or synchronous) event?

My first idea was to write the function with a name. That way, I can bind it to the *click* event to my button and also call it whenever I want to. However, in the case I wrote an anonymous function, what are my options?

Example (pseudo-code):

```
create button b;
assign some function f to b to execute on click;
b.invoke(args); //invoke runs f without the need to click
```

Comment: There may be hacky workarounds, but your best option by far is to use a named function.

Comment: You can simulate a click on that element: `$("#MyButton").click()`. But this will call all click event listener on that element.

Comment: `$('#MyButton, #OtherButton').click(/* do stuff */);`?

Comment: @DavidThomas , I'll write some pseudo-code to help the illustration. I'm not sure if I get your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire the "click" event on the element.

```
$('#MyButton').trigger('click');
```

**EDIT**: sorry, I misunderstood the question. But, you can still trigger the event and let the function to use some global variable so you can access everywhere.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but sounds like pretty much what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your edit. It seems that's exactly what I want. If trigger calls the anonymous function I registered for MyButton, than that's it.

Comment: You can't pass any parameter to it, I thought you wanted to do something more than trigger.

Comment: I understand. I desire to call the function with arguments. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, as I wrote, if you declare some global/function scope variables, you can access them by the function and manage them outside.